# Ring of honor, pride of the lions in NFL

Tags: american-football, nfl

I heard that [Ray Lewis](http://articles.baltimoresun.com/2013-09-17/sports/bal-lewis-humbled-by-ring-of-honor-induction-20130917_1_ray-lewis-super-bowl-xlvii-ravens-coach-john-harbaugh) will be inducted in the Ring of honor. Do all NFL teams have their own version of this ring of honor?

Besides special recognition, is there any other special rites as a member of this exclusive group?

Comment: I don't see any mentions of special 'rites' for players in the [Raven's Ring of Honor](http://www.baltimoreravens.com/team/history/ring-of-honor.html). It appears to be a simple way of that franchise honoring players who have significantly impacted the team -- on and off -- the field.

Comment: If you google search for [NFL Team's Ring of Honor](https://www.google.com/search?q=NFL+Team's+Former+Players+Honor+groups&oq=NFL+Team's+Former+Players+Honor+groups&aqs=chrome..69i57.10309j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=nfl+team's+ring+of+honor&safe=off), there's mention of many different team's Ring of Honors. I see Ravens, Browns, Vikings, Falcons, Giants, etc., right away. Assume almost all teams have one.

Comment: um, are you asking about 'rites' or 'rights'?

Comment: An example of "rites" would be [Ray Lewis ascending into heaven](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c7tgrxzme3o&feature=youtu.be&t=2m21s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most NFL teams display the names of past great players inside their stadiums.  Often this is referred to as the Ring of Honor.  Each team has their own criteria for this recognition.

The Green Bay Packers, for example, have a very simple criteria: the names displayed inside Lambeau Field are all in the Pro Football Hall of Fame. ([22 Packers are in the Hall of Fame.](http://www.packers.com/history/hall-of-famers.html))